# find second maximum position in matrix (like max.col)

Tags: r, search, matrix, max

I'm trying to figure out a way to find the second maximum position for each row of a matrix, just like max.col function does, but for the second highest value.
Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: One option is to get the  max element  and replace it with lowest value.  Then do the max.col, but it is easier to do with `apply` i.e `apply(m1, 1, function(x) sort(x, decreasing = TRUE)[2])`

Comment: @akrun, it is certainly easier to do with `apply`, but wouldn't you need a little more code to deal with ties if you had them (and wanted them handled a certain way). Also does it need to be `which(x==sort(x,decreasing=TRUE)[2])` or something similar to get the column position?

Comment: @MikeH.  If you are using `max.col`, there is a potential risk when there is NAs.  Regarding the ties, it is not clear whether the OP had it in the dataset.  If there is ties, yes, it needs to be addressed.  But, max.col also fails in that bcz it have only options for first, last or random

Comment: @akrun, you're right. I suppose it depends on OP's intended use

Comment: Thanks everyone! Im trining a classifier based on a neural network, and i needed to find the second most probable predicted class. Im wondering, can i also save the value of the highest and second highest columns? as those are the posterior probabilities of each class, and it might be useful too later

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to replace the maximum value with `-Inf` and then take `max.col` a second time:

```
set.seed(1)
mat <- matrix(sample(1:15), nrow = 5)
#mat
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    4    9    2
#[2,]    6   10   13
#[3,]    8   14   12
#[4,]   11    5   15
#[5,]    3    1    7


max.col(replace(mat, cbind(1:5, max.col(mat)), -Inf))
#[1] 1 2 3 1 1
```

Using a second `max.col` is handy because if you had ties, you can still use `max.col` to handle them appropriately.

Comment: That will do, Thanks!